# How could owner of repository create a pull request for code review

Tags: git, github, merge, repository, pull

I have been coding a project for a last month and now team lead wants me to create a pull request so he could do some code review. 
The problem is that I am the owner of a github repo and I can't get my head around how to create a pull request. 
I have a main branch and couple of feature branches. After finishing a feature I would merge it into *main*, so now my *main* is about 50 commits. 
He wants me to do a pull request (all green, so I guess that means no commits there) so he would jump in it and write some code review there. 
My logic is this: I could create an *empty* branch and then make a pull request to *main* to get all the files from *main* to *empty*. But whatever I do all I get from github is either  "all commits in two branches are identical" or "these files are total different, cant create a pull request between them" 
What is the right logic when owner needs to create a pull request in his own repo so that  "Files changed" would all be green, no red?

Comment: Usually when you do a PR, it's to review the set of changes to be merged into an existing branch. Are you saying the request is to review all changes in the repo's entire history? (This sounds kind of funny but I guess it does make sense for brand new work.)

Comment: Yeah I guess the idea is that they want to see all the code that i wrote and have a convenient way to make comments and remarks so they want all project in the pull request)

Comment: Are you willing to rewrite your existing 50sih commits? If yes, do you have merge commits you wish to keep? And, does your root commit have changes in it that also need to be reviewed, or is it an empty commit? You could quickly look with something like this in bash:  `git show $(git log --reverse --format="%h" | head -1)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use pull requests, then push your feature branch to GitHub *instead of* merging it to main locally. You can then open a pull request, have your collaborator(s) and/or testing suite review the proposed changes, and then have GitHub manage the merge for you.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not about a specific change, but about reviewing your general code base, then GitHub PR reviews are not the right place. If it is about a specific change/commit/set of commits you have made, then the right way would be to create a branch with all confirmed good features (i.e., `main`) and have all the to-be-reviewed features on a feature-branch. It is not worth creating new empty branches to then merge *everything* over, because your team lead will have to read the entire codebase anyways... I don't have a good solution for an alternative, though.